# Routing problem through 2 hop in the LAN

Tags: ubuntu, routing, vpn

This is the scenario I'm facing with:

- firewall (Zyxel Zywall USG210) configured as default gateway, with LAN IP 172.29.0.1 /16
- 2nd firewall, directly connected with the 1st, with LAN IP 172.29.0.250 /16
- VPN site-to-site configured between the 2nd firewall and a remote LAN (10.60.223.0 /24)
- static route configured on the 1st firewall with: destination 10.60.223.0 /24, next-hop 172.29.0.250

Now, pinging 10.60.223.1 from a Ubuntu client (with IP 172.29.x.x) I receive this response:

```
From 10.60.223.1: icmp_seq=4 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 10.60.223.1)
64 bytes from 10.60.223.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=55 time=222 ms*
and the SSH connection to the same host fails.
```

The problem doesn't happen if:

- I use a Windows client (on the same LAN) instead of the Ubuntu one
- if I don't configure the static route on the firewall, and instead I propagate it through the DHCP server, that is another server in the LAN.